# Issue with network cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, sockets, wiring

We recently had a garden studio installed in our back garden and I asked them to lay a network cable (steel armoured) from the front of the house, where the main router is located, to the garden studio. The cable is terminated at both ends with a network socket, but I don't seem to have any network connection in the studio. This was tested by connecting my laptop to the network socket with a network cable on the studio side, and connecting one of the router outlet ports to the network socket on the house side with a network cable. Both network cables were tested separately and work just fine. Connecting my laptop directly to the same outlet port on the main router with one of the cables also work just fine.

I have checked the wiring of both sockets and it appears correct.

Home side socket wiring
[image: Home side socket wiring]

Studio side socket wiring
[image: Studio side socket wiring]

What else am I missing? Where could be the fault/issue?

**Update 13/12/22**

I have borrowed the network socket tester from IT at work, and indeed one of the wires isn't connected, even though it appears to be just from looking at the socket:

[image: Network socket testing]

I did a gentle tug test on the said wire on one of the sockets, and it just came off in my hand. I suspect maybe their punch down tool was a bit sharp and it cut the wire off. I repunched it down with the tool that IT lent to me and it all works now.

Thank you all for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Get them back to test their work.

Comment: Thanks, that's my fallback position. However, this was an extra that was not in the original quote and should have been settled at the end of the work, and they forgot to charge me for it. So I'm trying to see if I can fix it easily first before I can go down that road.

Comment: That looks like a _very_ large amount of untwisted wires... Maybe not an issue for short distances, but still very poorly done – the pairs should have stayed twisted all the way until the last 1cm or so (coming in from the middle, not from the sides), not untwisted for what appears to be a mile.

Comment: Buy or borrow a network cable tester. It could be a faulty connection in one of the sockets or a faulty cable.

Comment: If you want to try DIY, the first thing you'll need is an Ethernet tester with looback plug, so you can try diagnose without being able to see both ends at once. Once you have the results of the wiring continuity test, that will indicate what to do next. [BTW, cheap ones are not worth the money]

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I am planning to borrow an Ethernet tester from work to test as suggested. The loopback plug is a good idea. I estimated the distance using Google Maps of the network cable to be between 40 and 50m.

Comment: Yup, you either have to be able to see both ends at once without the loopback, or get someone on the phone watching the other end [nightmare of co-ordination, expecially if your assistant is not conversant with the system]

Comment: I have edited the question with an update following testing the socket. Thanks again for your help.